# PHP online print_r parser/tabifier?

Tags: php

Does anyone know a json-like parser, which can tabify a `print_r()` output, so its easier to inspect? 
Im looking for something similar like [jsonParser](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Would be great if you could expand/collapse nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer `var_export()` as it is actual code:

```
echo '<pre>' . var_export($data, true) . '</pre>';
```

Also, `highlight_string()` will make it prettier:

```
highlight_string(var_export($data, true));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the HTML pre-tag.

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($array); ?>
</pre>
```

> The HTML Preformatted Text (pre) represents preformatted text. Text within this element is typically displayed in a non-proportional font exactly as it is laid out in the file. Whitespaces inside this element are displayed as typed.

-https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

Answer (score 2):

@Emil is correct. Although, may I recommend this function:

[dumpr](https://github.com/fheyer/avelsieve/blob/master/include/dumpr.php)

It is a bloated formatting for var_dump. print_r() in pre tags is faster and more lightweight but this is amazing for debugging as it shows data types and also shows empty() variables.

Answer (score 0):

Simple trick

```
echo nl2br(print_r($var, true));
```

or using pre tag as @Emil suggested

```
printf("<pre>%s</pre>", print_r($var, true));
```

You can also check site source in browser it shows tabs properly.